# Specify trigger event for AWS lambda in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have the following main.tf file which creates an S3 bucket `my-tf-test-bucket-12567` and an AWS lambda `hasher_lambda`:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket-12567"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/src/hash.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/src/hash.py.zip"
}
 
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  # add S3 inline policies for lambda to be able to read/write from/to S3 bucket
  name = "iam_for_lambda"
 
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
 
resource "aws_lambda_function" "hasher_lambda" {
  filename      = data.archive_file.lambda.output_path
  function_name = "hasher_lambda"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "hash.handler"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
}
```

How can I configure the AWS lambda to be triggered by S3 bucket `my-tf-test-bucket-12567` in Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create an [`aws_s3_bucket_notification`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification) and `aws_lambda_permission` in order for the function to be invoked by S3 events.

Lambda permission:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.hasher_lambda.arn
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
}
```

Bucket notification:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.func.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
}
```

There can be several event notification types which may cause an invocation of the Lambda. The whole list can be found in the AWS docs: [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations).